# Three equals two!

Tags: bug

[But four doesn't equal five](http://www.anvari.org/shortjoke/Science_Humor/1211_im-not-sure-if-the-following-one-is-a-true-story-or-not-the-great-logician-bertrand-russell-or-was-it-a.html).

Saw "two events" in a rep list and expanded it, to get **three** events.  Bug?
[image]

Comment: Four does equal five! Upon seeing this, I checked my tab, and there's a 4 events that when expanded shows 5 :D Maybe it's something with the timeline? Because the 09:16 upvote looks like it's also present above?

Comment: I didn't notice that.  The titles were in different colors, so I assumed one was for a question and one for a comment.  But now I realize that was not a question I asked, only answered.

Answer (score 2):

This has its own question [on meta.se](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139091/369802). But **four does equal five!**

The upvote you received at 09:16 is still 'unread' (marked in yellow) at the top of the list. If you refresh the page, it should show 3 events. I was able to reproduce it in my reputation tab:

This one shows 'unread' reputation changes in yellow, the 22:34 upvote on 'Convincing superstitious people' is also shown in the event log for the entire question, but isn't counted as event nr. 5.

[image: The yellow shows unread upvotes]

Here, I refreshed the page. You can now see I have 5 events for that question, including the 22:34 upvote:

[image]

Apparently, things have been like this since 2012...

Comment: OK, then it is a bug.  But relatively harmless.